# How to use try catch for multiple sections of code raising the same Exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have the code below, the until function raises a `TimeoutException` if the lambda function does not return an element. The problem is, that there are multiple sections of code that raise the same error, both when closing the cookies footer and finding the product title. I imagine it would be incredibly difficult to debug if multiple sections of code raise the same Exception. I initially thought of using the check on the string converted error message `str(e)`, but the `TimeoutException` also does not provide a useful message. Should I wrap a `try-except` statement for each section of code?

thanks

```
try: 
            #Closes cookies footer
            reject_cookies_btn = self.wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-type='no']"))
            self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(reject_cookies_btn))
            reject_cookies_btn.click()

            #Finds the product title and sets the product_description dictionary
            product_title = self.wait.until(lambda driver : driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='title-name a-fonts--26 a-colors--black-t js-detail-title']"))
            product_description["title"] = product_title.text

except TimeoutException as e:
print(str(e))
```

Comment: Yes, that's what would solve your problem.

Comment: Does the traceback not contain the information you want?

Answer (score 0):

Since the exception is usually hit in the wait function, that will be the best place to use the try catch block cause i c you calling the said function multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that come to my mind would be to provide custom exceptions for each of the errors you described using custom exceptions, as described [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/user-defined-exception).

Also to maintain readable code you should rather put try; except only on the code that generates error.